# Making a RecyclerView or ListView expand in order to accomodate all items

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView`. Upon user's interactions items are being added to `RecyclerView`. I want `RecyclerView` to expand such that it shows all items, and the scrolling should be handled by `ScrollView` only.

Problem: even though `RecyclerView` height is set to `wrap_content`, after several items are added it doesn't expand anymore and becomes scrollable.

Is there a way to force `RecyclerView` (or `ListView`) to expand such that it shows all the items at once?

P.S. I know that I could obtain a similar behavior with e.g. `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView`, but, currently, I don't want to implement workarounds.

Comment: Nesting scrollable containers is an anti-pattern. You'll get scroll-fighting issues.

Comment: Also if it will show all views it will no more be recycling views.

Comment: Guys, thanks for pointing this out. However, my question is "how to do that", not "why not to do that".

Comment: But "what's the point in doing that"? If the items are all visible at once, then there will be no scroll at all.

Comment: @NoiseGenerator, that's exactly what I'd like to achieve. As I said - think `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView`.

Comment: I'm thinking to a LinearLayout inside of... nothing. Or it would make no sense at all. RecyclerViews, as ListViews are already scrollable containers. And they do show all their items by scrolling.

Comment: Did you try using `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: let me guess,the design goes like this - `ScrollView` has a `RecyclerView` inside it. Say `Scrollview` has either a fixed height or `match_parent` and `RecyclerView` has both match_parent's to fit the `ScrollView`. Now disable scrolling in the layoutmanager through `canScrollVertically()` and it should work.

Comment: @Debdeep, I already switched to `LinearLayout`, but just out of curiosity reverted back and disabled vertical scroll in the layout manager and it worked. This is probably one of these Android hacks that will bite me in the ass in a year, but I like it! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it suggests, we've a `ScrollView` at the top having a fixed height or `match_parent`. Inside a View matched to its parent. For the scrolling, disable the scroll in `canScrollVertically()` of the `View` you're using inside.

Comment: Small clarification: `canScrollVertically()` should be overridden in `LayoutManager` and return `false`.